# Datagridview cell value not updated when modified dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Based on the design requirements, the datagridview can not be edited directly by the user. It is in read-only mode. When the user double-clicks on the cell, the datagridview's read-only property becomes false and the cell accepts keyboard input. However, the raw keyboard input needs to be formatted before it goes in the cell. So, I intercept the KeyPress events as follows:

```
private void dgw_keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

At this point the cell is in edited mode and dirty mode. Then I update the Value property in a different method and call `dgw.Refresh()` which is supposed to display the updated value on the cell. But it won't.  it will update only when the current cell is not dirty and is not in edit mode. How can I force the cell display the updated value while it is still in edit mode?

Any ideas?

Comment: Not very clear on what you want to achieve, how are you capturing the `keypress` event and then modifying the input and assigning it to the grid. Please post all the relevant code, this doesn't give any insight of whatz causing the problem.

Comment: I tried InvalidateCell() UpdateCellValue() and Refresh() on the datagridview control with no luck. 
 I'm intercepting and ignoring the control's key events. Instead, I have a keyboard hook that records the keystrokes. I take the key events captured by the keyboard hook, modify the values and display them on the DGW cell.

Answer (score 12):

Use below to refresh the current cell's value, change to suit your EditingControl type

```
if (dgvMain.EditingControl is TextBox)
{
    dgvMain.EditingControl.Text = dgvMain.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
}
```

Another method:

> Call this method to force a cell to update its display value in edit
>   mode. This is useful when an external process modifies the cell value
>   and you want to notify the user of the change, even when a
>   user-specified change is lost as a result.[details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.refreshedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
dgvMain.RefreshEdit();
```

Comment: Thanks you such for the answer. Though the answer in 3 years old. It helped me like to reach the destiny.

Comment: Be sure to check EditingControl for null. Eg:    -

Comment: if (dgvMain.EditingControl != null)
{
 // do something
}

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that by implementing the [IDataGridViewEditingControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.aspx) interface. I think that's the way to get the most control over how the cell enters and leaves edit mode. You can find more details in section 5.11 of Mark Rideout's [DataGridView FAQ (DOC)](http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc)

Answer (score 0):

Try [DataGridView.EndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit.aspx) method.

> Commits and ends the edit operation on the current cell.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it doesn't help. I figured a work-around. Moving the focus out of the edited cell automatically refreshed the data in it. Then I put the focus back to that cell instantly which is a good enough solution for now. There is a very little flickering, that's the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the code below.

```
GrdBudgetTabOver.EndEdit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
dgv.EndEdit()
dgv.InvalidateCell(ColIdx, RowIdx)
```